Unexpected behavior with imePadding causing it to be applied after the keyboard animation
I have a simple PIN view with a centered OTP view and a button at the bottom. Both views have 'imePadding' applied to their parent components. After opening the view, sometimes, the button slides vertically with the keyboard animation, but other times, the keyboard fully opens and then the button suddenly appears on top of it after the animation fully completes. Also the OTP view doesn't move until the animation finishes, then it snaps. It's very strange, since it happens only sometimes.
My question is: Am I doing something wrong, or could this be a device issue (I doubt it since I can reproduce it in the simulator)?
If my explanation is unclear, I can provide a video
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
        .imePadding(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
     OTPView(
        modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(pinFocusRequester),
        otpText = viewModel.pin.value,
        onOtpTextChange = { code, _ ->
            viewModel.pin.value = code
        },
        onDone = {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
            viewModel.onNext()
        }
     )
}

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp)
        .imePadding(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
) {
    ETOrangeButton(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.next)
    ) {
        viewModel.onNext()
    }
}


Turns out, this only happens when im building the app from android studio. It doesn't happen in versions built for the play store. So its all good, i guess.
